# REST framework for Vert.x using Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, vert.x

I recently started to use Node.js to develop a simple REST server for a TODO application using the restify framework.
Now I want to rebuild my application using Vert.x with JS. Unfortunately, I could not find a REST framework for vert.x with JS (only one for Scala).
Are there any good ones out there or is it generally a bad idea to develop something like that using Javascript or is it just that Vert.x is not that widely spread at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know what you really mean by "rest framework".
I used Jersey in Java and I replaced it with the vert.x RouteMatcher -- In javascript would be

```
var matcher = new vertx.RouteMatcher();

matcher.get('/uppercase/:name', function(request) {
    var name = request.params()['name'];    
    request.response.end(name.toUpperCase());
});

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(matcher).listen(80);
```

Regards,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks a lot! I simply forgot to look it up in the vert.x docs and thought I had to use a framework for the route mapping as in Node.js...